# findAllUseCountTop1ByIsActiveOrderById(Boolean isActive) does not generate a query with "LIMIT 1"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Why does JPA not apply "LIMIT 1" to the query? 
I am trying to write a repository function in SpringBoot application to get the first result from the top where "isActive" is TRUE when ordered by ID. This function generates a query that does not include "LIMIT 1" this returns multiple results and is failing with "query did not return a unique result:4" exception. I am using Hibernate Core v5.3.7.Final with MySQL v8.0.12 as the database.

Generated Query :

```
select phoneinfo0_.id as id1_0_, phoneinfo0_.Phone as Phone2_0_, phoneinfo0_.isActive as isActive3_0_, phoneinfo0_.useCount as useCount4_0_ from contactNumbers phoneinfo0_ where phoneinfo0_.isActive=1 order by phoneinfo0_.id asc;
```

Result Returned :

```
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| id1_0_ | Phone2_0_  | isActive3_0_ | useCount4_0_ |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1 | 1111111111 |            1 |            0 |
|      2 | 9999999999 |            1 |            0 |
|      3 | 9000000000 |            1 |            0 |
|      4 | 2222222222 |            1 |            0 |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Also please tell me if "ORDER BY ID" is necessary or is it done by default on every select if ID is Primary key auto-incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename it to one of this:

```
findTop1UseCountByIsActiveOrderById(Boolean isActive)

findFirstUseCountByIsActiveOrderById(Boolean isActive)
```

Comment: Hi @KonstantinLabun thank you for such a quick response. I have tried it and it works when I remove UseCount from the function name. The JPA straight on ignores column that I want to select and selects whole table instead. I got what I need though so thank you. Just one thing do you know how to select just one particular column or why is JPA selecting whole table instead of just getting "UseCount"?

Comment: Methods names is quite straightforward thing. Not sure if it will allow you to solve your problem. Try to use JPQL for it:

Comment: I have just read about it. We cannot apparently. We have to use @Query when we want to select particular columns. My solution was "findFirstByIsActiveTrueOrderById()" as I always wanted only the active ones and getting whole object now as its other values could be used later. This helped too [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation].